# Delay when executing C program with VS Code

Tags: c, performance, visual-studio-code, execution

I'm using VS Code and GCC in Windows 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getDays(int month, int day)
{   
    int sum = 0;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < month; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7 || i == 8 || i == 10)
        {
            sum += 31;
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            sum += 28;
        }
        else
        {
            sum += 30;
        }
    }
    sum += day;
    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{   
    printf("month: ");
    int month, day;
    scanf("%d", &month);
    printf("day:");
    scanf("%d", &day);
    printf("from January 1st to now:%d", getDays(month, day));

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I can see this user input section `month:`  after 10 seconds. What's the matter in my code, or is it a different problem?

I want to see the user input section directly.

Comment: If the delay only occurs the first time after making a change to your code file but not subsequent runs I suspect that a fair part of the delay is preparing the program for execution.

Comment: Unrelated: what about February 29th? ;-)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I use window10, and gcc compiler. It occurs not only first time but every time.

Comment: maybe this is too simple, but I recommend doing something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/nrrxvfh1T) to discover how much actual time has elapsed from the time your program started until "month" is done printing.  It's perhaps a sure way to know if anti-virus is causing the delay, or what?

Comment: OT: Enter `1` and `1` as if today is 1st of Jan. Program reports "From Jan 1st to now is 1 day..." I'd expect the report to be 0 days difference.

Answer (score 1):

I get similar behavior for most programs I compile on macOS since version 13.04.  I suspect the system performs some mysterious analysis, trying to ensure the newly generated code is not a virus.  This is very annoying but I haven't found a fix for this yet.  This only occurs for the first execution of a compiled program.

Comment: This might be correct, but without clarification from the user on platform info, this is speculation and best suited to a comment.

Comment: @Chris: you, I agree, or perhaps as a separate question.